# Set up path for javac

Tags: java, ubuntu, path, javac

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

 
I'm trying to install jdk, jre.

---

However, I can not set path for javac.

 I have tried

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac" 1
```

It returns

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/javac is already managed by javac
```

---

Can anyone help me explain what happens and what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To format the table/code/error correctly, please add **4 leading** space to each line of the code. Thanks!

Comment: You want `update-java-alternatives`; `-l` and `-s` for list and set respectively.

Comment: @SteveFest Tks, I did not regconize that.

Comment: @Elliot Frisch Tks for your answer. However, I am new to Ubuntu so I don't really understand. Can you give me a clearer instruction? Or maybe can you suggest what I should find out more about to fix this problem? I have been searching answer and copy paste but it doesn't work.

Comment: `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It returns:
    `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for appletviewer`
Also for `jarsigner` `javac` `javadoc` `javah` `jconsole` `mozilla-javaplugin.so` `rmic` `serialver`
And: <br>
    `update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so` 
<br>
Does this mean I haven't install all of these things?

Comment: @NguyenDo No. Applets are dead. `javac` and `java` should work. Also, the jdk includes a jre.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In my Eclipse, it works. In the terminal, it doesn't. It suggests `The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:` But whenever I install there will be bug in the end `update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/javac is already managed by javac`